# Putting output from a Spring Batch item writer onto a Spring Integration message channel

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

What is the best way to take output from a Spring Batch item writer - obviously run as part of a job - and to place it onto a Spring Integration message channel? I understand that one option is to code a Spring Batch listener (extending ItemWriteListener), which would be injected with a message channel, and then to attach the listener to the batch job. Is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

One option to inject to the `ItemWriter` a Spring Integration `<gateway>`:

```
<int:gateway id="itemWriterGateway" service-interface="com.my.proj.MyGateway"/>


class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Foo> {

   @Autowired
   private MyGateway gateway;

   public void write(List<Foo> items) {
       for(Foo foo : items) {
           this.gateway.send(foo); 
       }
   }
}
```

Another option to use `ItemWriterAdapter`:

```
<bean id="myItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.adapter.ItemWriterAdapter">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="itemWriterGateway"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="send"/>
</bean>
```

I won't argue that `StepListener` may have value for you too. But here there is need to understand what you want to achieve using Spring Integration from Batch Job...

**UPDATE**

Actually, `Listener` won't help you, because the `ItemWriter` doesn't return anything and it encapsulates its logic around underlying resource.

As you say that you are using `StaxEventItemWriter` and its `Resource` is some output file, maybe there is a reason to decouple your logic and read that result `File` using `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>`...

**UPDATE 2**

> ) why won't the listener help

Because you need a result of `ItemReader`, otherwise you have to build your XML one more time in the SI flow from `items` (`ItemWriteListener#afterWrite`).

> How could the the StaxEventItemWriter output, and the inbound adapter connect to, a resource which is held in memory?

How does your `resource` is in memory, if `StaxEventItemWriter` requires that it should `exists`?

From other side you can **share** that resource with `ItemWriter` and some SI endpoint. And right: you can do it from `ChunkListener#afterChunk` and get your `resource` from, e.g. `jobParameters` and send it to the SI Gateway.

Comment: Thanks. We are using a StaxEventItemWriter as the item writer. How could we integrate that with the second option you mention, ItemWriterAdapter? The first option, to inject the gateway into the item writer, may be possible if we extend StaxEventItemWriter. Is the Listener apporach to cleaner and simpler way to go? Our requirement: we are using Spring batch to read from a database and then to output the result as xml. That xml then has to be put on a Spring Integration channel to send to an external process.

Comment: Thanks. Two questions: 1) why won't the listener help - Spring Batch has an ItemWriteListener interface, is that not appropriate here? 2) With StaxEventItemWriter, setting the resource to a file and using a Spring Integration file-inbound-channel-adapter may work, but it would presumably be very inefficient because of the disk access. How could the the StaxEventItemWriter output, and the inbound adapter connect to, a resource which is held in memory?

Comment: Artem, thanks. Is there an alternative to StaxEventItemWriter which would create, for instance, a DOMResult, which a listener could then pick up and place on a Spring Integration channel? Otherwise, would this be a possible approach:use an item processor which calls a Spring OXM marshaller to create the DOMResult as a string, and use a JMS item writer to sent that to the external process (no Sprinng Integration).

Comment: 1. No, I don't know any alternative to `StaxEventItemWriter`. As I see in the Batch source code, there is no other XML `ItemWriter`s. Actually, you can extend `StaxEventItemWriter` and override `createStaxResult()` and get deal with that `Result`. 2. `ItemProcessor`. Yes, you always can implement your own solution and even without Spring Integration.